# Multi-Email Address Forwarding Not Working

Tags: email, centos, postfix

I am using POSTFIX on my CentOS server box to do email forwarding. The goal is to be able to create some simple forwarding addresses for the multiple domains on this box to route mail to a single gmail account; I got it setup and working for one email address just fine using the following pattern (in `/etc/postfix/virtual`):

```
info@domain1.com    mygmail@gmail.com
```

I just modified that same file (`sudo vi /etc/postfix/virtual`) so that I had multiple email addresses forwarding to the single gmail account; it now reads as follows:

```
info@domain1.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain2.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain3.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain4.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain5.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain6.com    mygmail@gmail.com
info@domain7.com    mygmail@gmail.com
```

From reading different articles the syntax should work; so I saved it and reloaded it:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
sudo newaliases
sudo postfix reload
sudo postfix stop
sudo postfix start
```

After attempting to commit the changes (rebuilding the `db` and refreshing everything; the new changes don't work. The old changes (line 1) still work. I have a strong sense of déjà vu from when I setup the first forwarder that I missed a step in refreshing everything but it is not coming to mind. I've even tried rebooting to no avail. I've also tried looking under `/var/log/` for a relevant log to see any errors but I'm not seeing even the log. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in dusan.bajic's comment here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972117/email-forwarding-not-working-with-postfix/

I failed to add the other domains to the `virtual_alias_domains` list in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. Having made this change and reloaded everything went through fine.